# AutoScroll div content both ways

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a div autoscroll it's content. The content height is variable. Here is what I managed to work out, but if I set the height to .childElement.outerHeight or height, it will only scroll 78px, I don't know why.

```
 var element = jQuery('#content');
            setInterval(scrollDown(element), 1000)

        function scrollDown(element) {
            var childElement = element.children();
            scrollAmount = childElement.outerHeight();
            element.animate({ scrollTop: 1000 }, 3000, null, scrollUp(childElement));
        }
        function scrollUp(element) {
            element.animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
        }

        });
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Sebastian

Comment: Have you tried css? Like `overflow: scroll` or `overflow: auto`?

Comment: I have overflow: hidden, I don't want to see the the scrollbar, just automatically scroll it slowly down, than auto scroll it back up, faster.

Comment: If you have solved your own problem, please post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution.

The main problem is that I used `document.ready`, and the div's child element did not have all the items in it so the scroll height was not correct. I've changed that with `window.load` and made some changes to the scroll animation. Also the parameters were wrong on the animate function.

Here is the final, working properly snippet.

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
    var element = jQuery('#content');
    var childElement = element.children();
    var scrollAmount = childElement.height();
    var speedDown = scrollAmount * 20;
    var speedUp = speedDown * 0.3;

    scrollDown(element, scrollAmount, speedUp, speedDown);

    function scrollDown(element, scrollAmount, speedUp, speedDown) {

        element.animate({ scrollTop: scrollAmount }, speedDown, function () {
            element.animate({ scrollTop: scrollAmount * -1 }, speedUp);
            scrollDown(element, scrollAmount, speedUp, speedDown);
        });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this on small, I've had a little line in your code for auto scrollUp and Down non-stop without mouseover timeout stop:

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
  var element = jQuery('#content');
  var childElement = element.children();
  var scrollAmount = childElement.height();
  var speedDown = scrollAmount * 50;
  var speedUp = speedDown * 0.9;

  scrollDown(element, scrollAmount, speedUp, speedDown);

  function scrollDown(element, scrollAmount, speedUp, speedDown) {

    element.animate({ scrollTop: scrollAmount }, speedDown, function () {
        element.animate({ scrollTop: scrollAmount * +3 }, speedUp);
        scrollDown(element, scrollAmount, speedUp, speedDown);
        element.animate({ scrollTop: scrollAmount * -3 }, speedDown);
    });
  }
})
```